# Create dataframe columns from list items

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

beginner to Pandas here. I have a function that generates a list of items that looks like this:

`['01/02/2020', '09:05:16', 29933, 2200, 6.8, 435, 1.35, 18, 16, 0.11, 'pre', '4033116']`

How can I go about creating a dataframe from this list, with column names?

Desired output dataframe would look something like this:

`Date         Time   Volume Rehandle Rehandle Pct...`

`01/02/2020 09:05:16 29933   2200      6.80      ...`

I'd also like to iterate through a list of these lists and create a dataframe of thousands of these items.
How can I go about doing this?

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(li).T;
df.columns = ......`

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, I actually figured it out. I was having trouble because I was trying to troubleshoot by using just a single row of data. After passing a list of lists, all is good.

I'd appreciate some constructive criticism on the code, however. Anything I can do to improve it?

Here is the fixed code.

```
passdown_list_of_lists = []

for sort_data in sort_files_list[0]:
    sort_instance = [passdown_generator(sort_data)]
    passdown_list_of_lists.append(sort_instance[0])

sort_instance_ = [text_cleaner(passdown_generator(sort_data))]

cols = ['Date','Time','Volume','Rehandle','Rehandle PCT','Reject','Reject PCT','SS1 No Xmit','SS2 No Xmit','No Xmit PCT','Sort', 'Sort ID']
sort_data_df = pd.DataFrame(passdown_list_of_lists, columns=cols)

print(sort_data_df.head(3))
```

Comment: what's `sort_files_list[0]`?

Comment: sort_files_list[0] is a list created by a function, index 0 contains a list of sort files.